# Excel percentage increase based on formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill the sell price column in an Excel spreadsheet with the increased values in colors based on the round up columns value (1 to 50 green, 50 to 100 blue, 100 to 150 yellow, 150+ pink).

I've opted for the percentage table because some items can be sold for a lot more than what I have purchased them for, so that's just for my benefit. I am open to any other suggestions and I am new to this whole business thing.

I was using `IF` in my formula which would work great for using one percentage increase in the formula:

```
 =IF($E27<50,ROUNDUP(I$27,-1))
```

If I try to enter a second argument like

```
=IF(OR($E28<50,ROUNDUP(I$28,-1)OR($E28>50,<100,ROUNDUP(J$28,-1))))
```

I will get an error.

I'm probably using the formulas wrong, I've tried "AND" and a couple other formulas, but I can't find anyone else trying to achieve the same or similar.

[image]

Comment: Is your 2nd `OR()` intended to mean: 50 < $E28 < 100?

Comment: higher than 50 but lower than 100 yes

Comment: What error did you get? What about columns and row addresses!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this:

```
=IF($E28<50,ROUNDUP(I$28,-1),IF($E28>50,ROUNDUP(J$28,-1),"Error"))
```

But not sure what the <100 was for.

Comment: if $E28 is above 50 and below 100, then the next arguement would be above 100 and below 150
no idea if I am entering the formula wrong

Comment: @Tonyb6 so first loguial test is "<50" then second is "<100", and  third is "<150" and so on, like my example. However putting lots of if() statements together is tedious, can be easier to do a table with the ranges and their results then use vlookup().

Comment: ok thanks mike ill give that a go

Comment: stopped using if and used IFS instead
forumula now looks like this:
=IFS(E3<50,ROUNDUP(I3,-1),E3<100,ROUNDUP(J3,-1),E3<150,ROUNDUP(K3,-1),E3>150,ROUNDUP(L3,-1))
and it works perfectly! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem is not completely clear, I understand that you want to add a formula with nested if statements.
I will recommend you to try nested ifs in parts.

```
=IF($E27<50,ROUNDUP(I$27,-1),"First if condition is false")
```

If everything is working as per the requirement then edit that text in the formula to add another if statement.

```
=IF($E27<50,ROUNDUP(I$27,-1),IF(OR(condition 1, condition 2,more conditions),"value if true","value if false"))
```

In the second argument provided by you, the arguments of the OR function has not been properly provided. Ensure that all the arguments of an OR function are conditions separated by a comma.
$E28<50 This is a condition so it's ok.
But other arguments are not making sense.
Also, using OR multiple times inside the first OR arguments is not clear.
It would be beneficial if you could provide the basic table and mention the requirement clearly.

Comment: ill have to try those formulas later when i get the chance thank you
I have used excel all of 3 weeks so i think ive bitten off more than i can chew
so if the value in roundup column is below 50 i want the value in the 50% column, same row to round to nearest 10
if the value in roundup column is above 50 but below 100, it rounds up the value in the 45% column
between 100 and 150, rounds up 35% column and so on
i have edited a better picture in and sorry if i make things hard